# Where can I find an exhaustive list of meta tags and what they do?

Tags: meta-tags

It seems to me that there are **a ton** of `<meta>` tags for all sorts of different purposes out there...

Though they all follow a similar format of

```
<meta name="" content="" />
```

they seem to serve a vast variety of different purposes from controlling the crawling of search engine bots, providing search engine bots with descriptions of pages, to making sure a page display correctly on a mobile device.

These tags fall into so many different categories I was wondering if anyone had a wiki or master list of possible meta tags and their content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia's article on the Meta Element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) covers all of the "standard" ones. There can be an unlimited number of values for this since anyone can make up their own meta tag to suit their purposes so you won't find an exhaustive list anywhere.